# vb.net connecting to MQ server

Tags: vb.net, ibm-mq, mq

I migrated app from vb6 to vb.net, every thing is working fine except getting the message from the MQ server, when MQGet called, I get 2033 error (no Message)
also attached the capture message that sent to MQ from working vb6 and from not working vb.net, please help?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F4ZM.png)

```
    '***********************************
    'Send(MQPUT) to MQSeries and CICS
    '***********************************
    PutMsgOpts = MQPMO_DEFAULT

    MsgDesc = MQMD_DEFAULT
    MsgDesc.Persistence = MQPER_PERSISTENT
    MsgDesc.MsgId = MQMI_NONE.Value
    MsgDesc.CorrelId = "AMQ!NEW_SESSION_CORRELID" 'if using MQBridge
    MsgDesc.ReplyToQ = gReplyToQ
    MsgDesc.ReplyToQMgr = gMQRplyMgrName
    MsgDesc.Format_Renamed = MQFMT_STRING

    'sPutMsg is composed of 8 byte program name(host/cics)
    ' plus data desired to pass as string only (dfcommarea)
    '************  MAX LENGTH IS 32776  *******************
    sPutMsg = gCICSPrgName & gsHost_Msg
    If Len(sPutMsg) <> 32768 Then
        sPutMsg = sPutMsg & Space(32768 - Len(sPutMsg))
    End If

    sMsgIdGet.Value = MsgDesc.MsgId

    '*******************************************
    'MQClose the queue for request sent to host
    '*******************************************
    'HOST-BYPASS
    MQCLOSE(Hconn, Hobj, MQCO_NONE, cC, Reason)
    'HOST-BYPASS

    '**********************************************************
    'MQOpen the queue for receiving the request from the host
    '**********************************************************

    'set up the queue name
    ObjDesc = MQOD_DEFAULT
    ObjDesc.ObjectName = gReplyToQ

    'Open
    'HOST-BYPASS
    MQOPEN(Hconn, ObjDesc, MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF Or MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING, Hobj, cC, Reason)
    'HOST-BYPASS
    'Hconn is set by MQseries in the Connect

    '**************************************
    'Receive (MQGET) from MQSeries and CICS
    '**************************************
    GetMsgOpts = MQGMO_DEFAULT
    GetMsgOpts.Options = MQGMO_WAIT Or MQGMO_CONVERT
    GetMsgOpts.WaitInterval = 10000 '20 seconds

    MsgDesc = MQMD_DEFAULT
    MsgDesc.Format_Renamed = MQFMT_STRING
    MsgDesc.Persistence = MQPER_PERSISTENT
    MsgDesc.CorrelId = sMsgIdGet.Value 'set correlId with MQGET msgid returned
    MsgDesc.MsgId = MQMI_NONE.Value
    MsgDesc.ReplyToQ = gReplyToQ
    MsgDesc.ReplyToQMgr = gMQRplyMgrName

    '** sGetMsg is composed of 8 byte program name(host/cics)
    '** plus data desired to pass as string only (dfcommarea)

    '************  MAX LENGTH IS 32776  *******************
    sGetMsg = New String(" ", 32768)

    'Command to receive from to MQSeries and CICS
    retryCount = 0
    cC = MQCC_OK + 1
    Reason = 2033
    Do While cC <> MQCC_OK And Reason = 2033
        MQGET(Hconn, Hobj, MsgDesc, GetMsgOpts, Len(sGetMsg), sGetMsg, readlen, cC, Reason)
        retryCount = retryCount + 1
        If retryCount > 1 Then Exit Do
    Loop 
    '************************
    'MQClose queue for input
    '************************
    MQCLOSE(Hconn, Hobj, MQCO_NONE, cC, Reason)
```

Comment: it worked by doing:
Dim MyNewCorrelID As String = "AMQ!NEW_SESSION_CORRELID"
mqMsg.CorrelationId = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MyNewCorrelID) 
when I put the message and also use 
mqMsg.CorrelationId = mqMsg.MessageId when I get the message.  
but I have another problem that I can not read the message as a String.
1-System.Console.WriteLine(mqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength))
2-message_string = mqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength)
the first line write the message that I want in the console line, the second line give me "Unable to read beyond the end of the stream", Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you get 2033, then you know the queue is there, but the message you are trying to retrieve is not. Use MQ Explorer or plain MQ samples along with runmqsc to check if there are any messages on that queue, and if there are, if their correlation id matches what your program is supplying.

If there are no messages there, then check that your messages have been indeed received by the CICS program your are sending them to, and if that program responded.

A 2033 problem may be your coding problem, but more probably it's something in the configuration and setup that has changed along with your conversion. You may have a differently configured queue manager, with differently configured channels etc. Check the entire chain.

Comment: Thank you ValerieLampkin, please I am new to MQ and do not know a lot about it and even to vb.net, please can you to the attached file between the message from working VB6 and VB.net, you may know what attribute I am passing wrong in vb.net.

Comment: I can't see any difference between the messages, of course I haven't followed every bit on the screenshot - you are in a better position to save messages and compare files to make sure. But what I am saying is it is not only the way you create and send messages that matters - your entire setup matters. You aren't saying anything about the rest of the system - are you using the same setup or a new one? Is it the same queue manager or not? How are the remote queues and channels configured? In short, follow the message flow and find the place where it goes wrong.